# Including SO's url creates a link that isn't closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

This popped up in Adam Davis's revision to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/playful-parodies-possibly-pose-plenty-perplexing-problems/29485#29485).  Including the `http://stackoverflow.com` in the block quote seems to be creating a link that is never closed.  Let's try to reproduce it here:

> http://stackoverflow.com

If the bug behaves as I suspect it does, this text will be part of the link.  Well, that didn't do it, so forgive me as I include more of this text and try to pare it down to the problem...

---

Here is the email trail and a few notes on what occurred when per Rich B:

Rich's account is changed from Chet Atwood to Rich B by stackoverflow team, then Rich received this email:

> **SUBJECT:** your avatar
>   **FROM:** stackoverflow team
>    Fri, Nov 6,
>   2009 at 11:26 AM
>   **TO:** Chet Atwood
>   **BODY**:
>   Please desist, or there will be
>   consequences.
>
> --
>
> ---
>
> http://stackoverflow.com

Rich responded:

> **SUBJECT:** RE: your avatar
>   **FROM:** Chet Atwood Fri, Nov 6, 2009 at 12:58
>   PM
>   **TO:** stackoverflow team
>
> Please desist what, precisely?

---

Oh yeah, that did it.

Comment: it worked.  booya

Comment: Yeah, I decided not to try and fiddle with it to find a way around it.  It's annoying, and hopefully fixable, but I've run into far too many link-related markdown issues to care anymore.

Comment: Looks like you found a good workaround for the time being, though: "Put the stackoverflow URLs in backticks to fix the bizarre link bug."

Comment: Actually, it did do it in your first quote. The `</a>` is not in source, and in Firefox, I'm seeing everything from there til `team@stackoverflow.com` as a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This had to do with the legacy "encode email addresses" support in our markdown server-side processor.

Things like

`<team@stackoverflow.com>`

**technically get encoded to mailto: URLs in Markdown**, but we've never really supported that (email, feh, I spit on email). But I never removed that support from the Markdown processor on the server, either, so it was still being emitted.

I removed it now since a) we weren't using it and b) it generates some dumb markup that causes issues.

Answer (score 1):

### The results

I ran several tests over the course of several edits, and discovered the following:

1. The first time, the SO link did overflow, right up to my manually-inserted `</a>` tag.
2. The second time, where I added the Google link, no overflow from Google, but SO still did.
3. The third time, when I added all of the other Trilogy links, SO overflowed *past* my manual `</a>`, Google overflowed, the Meta link overflowed, and SU and SF did not overflow.

My gut reaction: This thing's freakin' unpredictable. It'll happen sometimes, or it won't, but the best way to use real links is to use MarkDown's syntax, and if you're embedding a URL in a quote, use the backtick method mentioned in the comments. I have no clue what this post will look like when I submit this fourth (and probably final) time.

### The test

Here's a simple test. You can use your browser's "View Source" feature to see it in action:

> http://www.stackoverflow.com

And all this should be a link. Right up until ... here, where I manually insert a `</a>`.

OK, with that out of the way, is the problem just relegated to SO links, or can other links cause the problem too? Let's ... find out!

> http://www.google.com

Is this still a link? Hrm ... Negative!

How about the other Trilogy sites?

> http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Is this still a link? Hrm ...

> http://www.superuser.com

Is this still a link? Hrm ...

> http://www.serverfault.com

Is this still a link? Hrm ...

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, I notice that the SU and SF links are nofollow'd.

Comment: My results were observed in Firefox 3.5.5 on Windows 7, BTW. And regardless of browser behavior for handling the unclosed links, the links -- except SU and SF, for some reason! -- are all unclosed in the `blockquote` tags, if you view the page source.

Comment: @mmyers: I think all of the external links are nofollow'd.

Comment: Turns out my manual `</a>` was stripped; that'll do it.

Comment: Sooo... the lesson here is "basic HTML is hard, let's go shopping"?

Comment: I think the lesson is that MarkDown, while awesome, is hardly perfect. But we all already knew that.

Comment: this is actually a totally different bug than what the OP posted.

Comment: Is this part of the [status-completed], or should it be reported separately? (And from the outside looking in, it looks like the same bug ... )

Comment: "fixed" by making the tag balancing algorithm go in forward order when pairing and doing a second pass in reverse for orphan removal. Previously it did a 1-pass reverse. Details at http://refactormycode.com/codes/360-balance-html-tags

Comment: Total fix; awesome.