# Is mailto supported?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I was wondering if [mailto](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html) is supported on posts, let me try it:

Contact

I guess not =o(

Answer (score 6):

`mailto` is not supported in posts. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29500/including-sos-url-creates-a-link-that-isnt-closed/29523#29523) for the official establishment of this.