# Clickable email address

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I've found that there are some cases where an email address or a phone number may need to be specified in an answer, however, it doesn't seem possible to make that email a clickable link.

Is this intended by design or just never thought to be necessary?

Case in point: Regulatory websites with specific email address and phone numbers:

[Will I be stopped at customs if I bring the shell of a cicada through US customs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/will-i-be-stopped-at-customs-if-i-bring-the-shell-of-a-cicada-through-us-customs)

Comment: As far as I remember, Skype has a browser plugin that converts phone numbers to clickable form, it's up to the visitor of the site to install it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's by design.

[Is mailto supported?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54774/is-mailto-supported?s=1|2.1624) leads to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29500/including-sos-url-creates-a-link-that-isnt-closed/29523#29523) on [Including SO's url creates a link that isn't closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29500) which says, in part:

> ...but we've never really supported that (email, feh, I spit on email). But I never removed that support from the Markdown processor... I removed it now ...